# NGINX cookieless domain

Tags: nginx, webserver, cookieless

I have an NGINX server serving static assets from a domain *assets.example.com*. As per Pingdom's tools test, I get a report asking me to serve the static assets from a cookieless domain.("**Serve static content from a cookieless domain**")

I have tried adding the following code `fastcgi_hide_header Set-Cookie;` in the *server* section of NGINX vhost config file. It isn't working. Can anyone assist me ?